# Synergy, I am missing mouse cursor on client machine

Tags: windows-xp, synergy

I have installed Synergy Server on my laptop, and the Client side of things on my Virtual Desktop Session, both running a Win XP environment.  I am able to connect no problem. When I move mouse to client machine, I can click on items and activate them, but I do not see my Mouse Cursor from the server.  I can use keyboard shortcuts, but its a real pain trying to operate 2nd machine, with no mouse pointer.

Any ideas?

As a clarification, I have installed the Synergy Release as of Feb 20th (newest install) and when I stated that I installed the client on one and server on other, I was making incorrect generalizations. I installed same installer on both, just wanted to clarify which I was using as server, and which as client.

Comment: please delete your comment and add it as an update to your question; you can edit your question as many times as you like...

Comment: What do you mean by "virtual desktop session"? Is it a Citrix or RDP session being displayed on a different computer than your laptop?

Comment: or is it a VMware/VirtualPC/VirtualBox desktop?  Sounds fishy when you say Virtual Desktop Session.  Dont get why you would need synergy in either case or Citrix's for that matter.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Synergy? Have you tried an older version? Also, you should try this search query ([synergy ~mouse ~hidden ~problem](http://www.google.com/search?q=synergy+~mouse+~hidden+~problem)) on Google, it will search for different kinds of similar queries so you get the most accurate results...

Comment: you may try newer - beta versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly solution to your Synergy issue but Microsoft [have released](http://blogs.technet.com/b/next/archive/2011/09/09/microsoft-garage-download-mouse-without-borders.aspx) similar software and I can say that it's equal if not better than the one you're using now.

So if you cannot find viable solution [give it a try](http://blogs.technet.com/b/next/archive/2011/09/09/microsoft-garage-download-mouse-without-borders.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Different reports](http://www.google.com/search?q=synergy+~mouse+~hidden+~problem) reveals possible (and working) fixes:

- Remove an application called SecureCRT, check for other conflicting software.
- Run the Synergy application in an administrator context.
- Reinstall Synergy.
- Get a different version, which might no longer include the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Synergy a little bit buggy, I use it only if I must control different OSes (linux with windows) but if they are windows computers, I use [Input director](http://www.inputdirector.com/), its free and easier to set up

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.

Turned out connecting a mouse to my client machine resolved it. My guess is X isn't rendering a cursor on machines without a hardware pointing device. I bet it has to do with handling touchscreens without curors.

I'm just leaving my house hooked-up. But I bet there's an X config parameter for this too.